# How to change the mysql query in datagrid view?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` for which I added data using the user interface I selected a particular column from a table in the data base.

The default query it uses is:

```
select wine from cms.menulist
```

I want to edit this to:

```
select wine from cms.menulist where wine<>'null'
```

How can I achieve this?
Where can I change the sql query?
When I click on the arrow on the top right of the `DataGridView` and select add query it gives me an error.

Comment: error invoking add query

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
SELECT 
    wine 
FROM 
    cms.menulist 
WHERE 
    wine IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: i used ur query yet im getting the "error invoking add query" error

Answer (score 0):

check which dataset is populating the datagridview
find that dataset in solution explorer and open it
right click on the dataset and select configure
edit the query and click next and finish